# Convert from Oracle VARCHAR2 to MySQL TEXT

Tags: mysql, oracle, text, varchar2

How to do correct conversion of data from Oracle VARCHAR2 type to MySQL TEXT type? 
I want insert it into mysql table in field with TEXT type through DBLink.

Comment: job well done. 
str:='insert into "tabledst"@mysqlhs ("str")  values(' || chr(39) || msg || chr(39) || ')';
execute immediate str;

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. I wasn't sure which way you are going but the Oracle package dbms_lob will convert varchar2 to various BLOB, LOB, CLOB formats.

You might need to use a temporary table to pull source data to target side first if there are problems with the database link.

```
insert into database.target_table@DBLINK(text1, text2)
select 
  dbms_lob.substr(s.text1, 4000, 1),
  dbms_lob.substr(s.text2, 4000, 1)
from 
  source_table s;
```